# How to restart some windows services when computer boots up / wakes up?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

Here's the thing... at some point, something got messed up on my Windows 10. Instead of the computer going to sleep/hibernation after 5 minutes of inactivity, it sometimes stays on until i manually turn it off.

In any case, after doing some investigation, i pinpointed that "Windows Update" and "Windows Update Medic Service" are the culprits. So when the system gets in this state when it doesn't want to go to sleep, i just manually restart those two services and everything is back in order.

The question really is - what can i do to automate this process? Would a powershell script work, or some other setting somewhere?

I can't really ask anyone to give me such a script (would be great tho) so nudging in the most technically correct way to tackle/fix this would be the answer i'm kinda looking for. Perhaps restarting those two services isn't the ideal approach either, but it's one that will surely work though.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a few things wrong including some updates and drivers. Windows Services are usually automatic.

Update all your drivers. Hopefully your computer manufacturer has a driver update app. Use that if there is one. Otherwise go to the Support site and download / install all drivers.

Then do a Windows 10 Repair Install. This is preferred here because apparently there is more than one thing wrong.

Note the 3 possible ways to do a Repair Install. Start with Keep Everything and see if that works.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

At the end, go into Advanced Power Management and set up Sleep to your preferences.  I avoid Hibernation because it can cause issues. After all the updates it may work for you.

Follow all the steps and good luck.